# zero pad wmic output inside for loop of batch file

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I don't think the below batch file needs `enableDelayedExpansion` but somehow I'm overlooking the problem of the nested if/else tree inside the for loop.

I've commented the expected actions using `::`.

It gets either into the "prepend 0" (when `%%b` is empty, I expected less than 10) or "no prepend" clause.

Given this batch file:

```
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a IN ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime get * /format:list ^| findstr "="' ) do (
    echo wmic_%%a=%%b
    if "%%b"=="" (
      :: empty becomes 00
      set wmic_%%a=00
    ) else (
    if %%b LSS 10 (
        :: 0 prepend
        set wmic_%%a=0%%b
      ) else (
        :: no prepend
        set wmic_%%a=%%b
      )
    )
  )
  set | findstr "wmic_"
  endlocal
```

the wmic statement gives a list like this:

```
Day=21
DayOfWeek=4
Hour=15
Milliseconds=
Minute=4
Month=5
Quarter=2
Second=22
WeekInMonth=4
Year=2015
```

I wanted to have this expanded to this:

```
wmic_Day=21
wmic_DayOfWeek=04
wmic_Hour=15
wmic_Milliseconds=00
wmic_Minute=02
wmic_Month=05
wmic_Quarter=02
wmic_Second=22
wmic_WeekInMonth=04
wmic_Year=2015
```

But I got non-zero expanded variables like this:

```
wmic_Day=21
wmic_DayOfWeek=4
wmic_Hour=15
wmic_Milliseconds=0
wmic_Minute=2
wmic_Month=5
wmic_Quarter=2
wmic_Second=22
wmic_WeekInMonth=4
wmic_Year=2015
```

Comment: `::` is technically a label, which has a history of breaking things inside of `for` loops and `if` statements. Use `rem` instead.

Comment: Without the labels I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with SomethingDark.  `::` shouldn't be used within a parenthetical code block.

Also, I think part of the problem is that the encoding of values returned from WMI queries are encoded in UCS-2 Little Endian, which does weird things to an ANSI runtime.  I found a way to get around that using `set /a`, appending `.0` to each value (which is immediately dropped, since `set /a` only computes integers), and black holing error messages.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('wmic path win32_localtime get * /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (
    2>NUL set /a "wmic_%%I.0"
)
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%I in ('set wmic_') do (
    if %%J leq 9 set "%%I=0%%J"
)

set wmic_
```

It's ugly, but it seems to produce the output you want.  The end justifies the means, I guess.  :)

Comment: You are right. Added () around all assignments and found spurious line breaks.